# Parent, Child & GrandChild Relationships case on Input Select

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

How can we get the parent and child relationship both on input select option if we using blade method for input select button. I am getting all the data without sorting on select but I need to see child below parent in select and child should be having a bullet or something to get to know its a child of above parent.

**Blade**

```
{!! Form::select('parent_id',$categories,old('parent_id'),[
    'placeholder' => trans('test.parent_id'),
    'class' => 'form-control',
]) !!}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data=[
    'categories' => Category::with('children')->pluck('category','id'),
];
return view('backend.categories.modals.create', $data);
```

**Model**

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id')->Active();
}

public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id','id')->Active();
}

public function scopeActive($query) {
    return $query->where('active',1);
}
```

The select output which I am getting by this is:
[image]

The output which I want is something like below:

**Homepage**

- *Homepage child*

**Contact Page**

- **Contact child page**
- contact childs child page

I don't know where am I going wrong do I have to do some other trick to get the output I desire for, if yes what's the best trick we can do to get it done?

**DB Structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `optgroup` with plain html to display the options in groups

```
<select>
   @foreach($categories as $category)
        <optgroup>
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category }}</option>
                @foreach($category->children as $child)
                    <option value="{{ $child->id }}">{{ $child->category }}</option>

                    @foreach($child->children as $kid)
                        <option value="{{ $kid->id }}">{{ $kid->category }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
        </optgroup
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And you need to remove the `pluck` and write

```php
$data=[
    'categories' => Category::has('children')
        ->orWhere('parent_id', 0)    //Get only the parents
        ->with(['children' => function($query){
            $query->doesntHave('children');
        }])
        ->select('category','id')
        ->get(),
];
return view('backend.categories.modals.create', $data);
```

Comment: I tried above code it threw me an error Trying to get property 'category' of non-object

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you were using pluck. You need to pull the objects for category. `pluck` converts to an array. Check the updated code

Comment: I don't use null for parents because in my case even child can be a parent and only if child is parent it would be bold and its children would list below that child or parent

Comment: The root parents are places with `0 int`

Comment: How would you identify whether a particular record is a parent or child? That condition needs to replace `whereNull('parent_id')`

Comment: I have updated the issue in which I have inserted db structure. That's how I was trying to identify the parent and child

Comment: Have updated the code in answer just had o replace whereNull('parent_id') with where('parent_id', 0)

Comment: I tried the updated code, its close enough just 2 issues found 
1st issue: The very 1st root parent shows 2 times and the first one gets bold, other parents doesn't get bold
2nd issue: If you see the db structure the parent of child id 4 is id 3 and this 4th id is not showing up, I think because of `where('parent_id',0)`

Comment: The parent category is showing two times because of label on optgroup you may change the label to anything or even remove it all together. I didn't understand the other issue you are having

Comment: Okay I got it now 2nd issue the record with id 4 is a subchild of a child which is not provisioned for in the query hence not showing. Query needs to be defined in such a way that `parent->child->grandchild` hierarchy is obtained

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225573/discussion-between-hardik-sisodia-and-donkarnash).

Comment: the parent_id  with 0 value is not showing up in options if that parent has no child under it just checked

Comment: Adding  `orWhere('parent_id', 0)` as updated above in the answer should get the records without any child records as well - pls check the updated code

Answer (score 1):

First of thing you have to alter query to get only parent categories.

```
$categories=Category::active()->get()->groupBy('parent_id');
$data=[
    'categories' => $categories,
    'rootCategories'=>data_get($categories,0)

];
```

in View

```html
<select name='parent_id' class="form-control">
     <option value="">{{ trans('test.parent_id') }}</option>
     @foreach($rootCategories as $rootCategory)
                                            
          <option value="{{ $rootCategory->id }}" {{old('parent_id')==$rootCategory->id?'selected':''}} class="optionGroup">{{ $category->category }}</option>
               @if(data_get($categories,$rootCategory-id))
                    @foreach(data_get($categories,$rootCategory-id) as $children)
                         <option class="{{data_get($categories,$children-id)?'optionGroup':'optionChild'}}" value="{{ $children->id }}" {{old('parent_id')==$children->id?'selected':''}}>{{ $children->category }}</option>
                         @if(data_get($categories,$children-id))
                               @foreach(data_get($categories,$children-id) as $children)
                                   <option class="{{data_get($categories,$children-id)?'optionGroup':'optionChild'}}" value="{{ $children->id }}" {{old('parent_id')==$children->id?'selected':''}}>{{ $children->category }}</option>
                                   @if(data_get($categories,$children-id))
                                         @foreach(data_get($categories,$children-id) as $children)
                                             <option class="{{data_get($categories,$children-id)?'optionGroup':'optionChild'}}" value="{{ $children->id }}" {{old('parent_id')==$children->id?'selected':''}}>{{ $children->category }}</option>
                                             @if(data_get($categories,$children-id))
                                               //here we are a recursion you have to make a blade to handle recursion and call it self if item has childern 
                                             @endif
                                          @endforeach
                                   @endif
                               @endforeach
                         @endif
                    @endforeach
              @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

you have to add css for class optionGroup and optionChild similar like this code

```css
.optionGroup {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
    
.optionChild {
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: I don't use null for parents because in my case even child can be a parent and only if child is parent it would be bold and its children would list below that child or parent, The root parents are places with `0 int`

Comment: so replace whereNull('parent_id') to be where('parent_id',0)

Comment: Also in this case I am not able to select parent options

Comment: I tried putting `where('parent_id',0)` but still didn't work parent option is not getting selected

Comment: yes you have to replace code to make parent as an option please check updates in few.

Comment: I tried your updated code. If you see the db structure the parent of child id 4 is id 3 and this 4th id is not showing up, I think because of `where('parent_id',0)`

Comment: yes because my code works if for only one level 
parent -> children 
in your case you have to remove where('parent_id,0)
but also you have to replace to get all categories with nested levels. let me make a solution for nested levels for you '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225574/discussion-between-hardik-sisodia-and-anas-omush).

Comment: please check updated code and hints for recursion and changes on css. current code maybe render to or three level at max when you make recursion blade and call it self when item has children will be infinity level